# Raising Polar to the Power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

Ok guys, I'm back! This is gonna be my last question here, as I have practically finished test review.

Raise to the the power:

b ) $(8 cis(120 ^\circ)))^{1/3}$

... Well for this there are two formulas available.. I'm asking which one am I suppose to use for this equation?

1) $z^n = r^n * cos(n*\Theta)$

$x^{1/n} = r^{1/n}\frac{1}{n} \cdot \Theta + \frac{1}{n} \cdot 360k$

2) So I just decided to use first one.. and did:

$8^{1/3} cis(\frac{1}{3} \cdot 120^\circ)$

$2cis(40)$

But the answers are:

> $$2cis(40^\circ) , 2cis(160^\circ), 2cis(280^\circ)$$

Comment: In general there are a total of $n$ "$n^{th}$ roots" of a number (generally the one closest to the positive real axis is referred to as the "principle root").  All of the roots will be the same distance from the origin, and they will be evenly spread around the circle.  You found the argument of the principle root was $40^{\circ}$, but the arguments of the remaining two roots will be $120^\circ$ and $240^\circ$ away from the original (since there are three and $360^\circ\cdot\frac{1}{3}=120^\circ$.  Hence, the arguments of the remaining two roots are $160^\circ$ and $280^\circ$

Comment: Ok I understand everything except the Why is it $120^\circ$ and $240^\circ$!! May you explain that please @JMoravitz ?

Comment: Nvm i got it @JMoravitz . Im just stupid....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used the second one.

Both of these formulae assume that $n$ is an integer, which means you can't plug in $n=1/3$ into the first equation. But you can plug in $n=3$ into the second equation.

(The only case when the two formulas could both be used is when raising to the power 1. You should check that you do get the same answer regardless of which formula you use.)

[Actually, the "right" answer is that both formulae work for $n$ not an integer as well, but you will generally get different answers; there is a reason for this but it is not so simple to explain. Based on the way that the answer is formatted, it seems that they want you to consider the integer case only.]

Comment: Can you show me how you would do it if you were going to use the second  one please?

Comment: I can, but I'm quite confident that you can plug in $n=3$ and get the answers yourself. Perhaps the $k$ is confusing you? You are supposed to let $k$ be any number between $0$ and $3-1=2$; notice that is three values for $k$, so you will get you three different answers, just like your answer key. (You are missing a "cis" in your formula, though, so you want to fix that before plugging it in.)

Comment: Ok Eric.. Now i have a new question.. I posted it on the main question comment section.

Comment: I'm not really interested in answering that question. If you use the formula as directed, you will see the numbers 120 and 240 emerge naturally. The reason they show up there is the same reason that they show up in Moravitz's comment. (And indeed, Moravitz's comment does a very good job of explaining why they show up at all, which may be more believable once you do it once or twice.)

Comment: Yeah i am just a stupid person... sorry. Thank you for your time kind sir

Comment: @Dsafds: No problem. fwiw, you're not stupid. It's just that it's not so easy to figure out when your misunderstanding is coming because you can't explain the concept, and when it's coming because you don't really believe the explanation :P